# How can a void sorting algorithm "return" a result?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, bubble-sort, pass-by-value

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sizeOfTestArray = 50;
    int[] testArray = new int[sizeOfTestArray];
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfTestArray; i++) {
        testArray[i] = random.nextInt(100);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testArray));
    bubbleSort(testArray);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testArray));
}

public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If Java is pass-by-value how is it that I can manipulate testArray inside my bubbleSort method and "return" the bubbleSorted testArray? Shouldn't the bubbleSorted testArray be destroyed after my program exits the bubbleSort method? Please help me understand this as I am getting conflicting information online as to whether or not Java is pass-by-value or pass-by-reference.

Comment: Callback interfaces can "pass back" results asynchronously

Comment: "Pass-by-value" means the reference to the array is passed.  You can still change the contents of the array.

Comment: To answer the actual question, though, you've given an array as the parameter, which it's "value" is a reference pointer to the array in memory. Any updates within the method will update this reference value.

Comment: The other thing the OP can do is just try it.  Call a method with an array parameter, swap a couple of elements in the array, then have the caller print out the array.  He'll see that the array changes are indeed visible to the caller.

Comment: You aren't returning a result. You are causing a side effect on an array, a reference to which you received by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If Java is pass-by-value how is it that I can manipulate testArray inside my bubbleSort method and "return" the bubbleSorted testArray?

Because arrays are *mutable*: Their state can be changed. So the method doesn't *return* anything, but it does change the state of the object referenced by the value you pass in.

What you're passing in (an object reference) is passed by value. But the object it refers to is elsewhere in memory, the reference is just a means of telling the JVM where it is. This is a different usage of the word "reference" than the one in pass-by-reference (which specifically is about a reference to a **variable**, not an object).

Comment: Java's terminology is a bit confusing if you're coming from other languages, but the above is 100% correct.  Remember that arrays are objects, and all objects (including arrays) exist on the heap.  Changes to heap memory are visible globally.

Comment: @markspace The object being located in the heap doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: @ELP Method parameters are typically passed on the stack.  Objects typically are stored on the heap.  Java's semantics for method parameters and objects derive directly from the way those areas of memory naturally work.  If you're trying to argue for some corner case or optimization, I think you're picking at nits.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array to any function the address of that array is passed which is present in the stack memory. No new array is formed, it's just the key which is passed to the function so that the function can access the data members.
Since array is a non primitive data type, the elements are present in the heap memory and the address of this continuous list is present in the stack memory. So when you pass an array the function directly works on the members present in the heap memory.
If you are new to java kindly read about primitive and non primitive data types and stack and heap memory.